# Sequence of boxes with arrows in the corners

Tags: pattern

[image]

This was a puzzle given "graduatetrader.com".
I don't have its answer but it wasn't **E** as per them.

If you can find some pattern please help me.

I found one pattern by giving numbers to each arrows: 1 to 4
Then number way to select a pair for any fixed diagonal(or any pair lets say right bottom and top etc) is 4C2=6
So only remaining item will give a solution, but it isn't in options.

Comment: One thing is pretty obvious: all squares in the top row have one of each arrow.  Among the options only E obeys that rule.  If E is not the intended answer then the puzzle is badly designed.    I would even consider E is the answer but there is mistake in the problem statement or in the solution sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I *would* choose E as the correct answer, as it's the only option out of the possibilities that returns you to the same square on a grid when all 4 moves are taken. Every other option puts you in a different ending square.

Comment: Sadly its not E.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer which is at least consistent and has only one answer among the choices (which is not E).

> If you look at which arrows are in each corner in the five given squares you get this:
>
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  Notice that in each corner exactly one arrow is repeated and that no corner has the same repeated arrow.

> If we now assume that the missing square must add one and only one additional new repeated arrow to each corner (so no corner has 3 repeated arrows), there is only one answer that fits.

> **B** doesn't work as it would add a third down arrow to the upper right corner. **D** and **E** don't work as they would add a third left arrow to the bottom right corner. **C** doesn't work as it would add a third right arrow to the bottom left corner.
>
>
>  But **A** works!

Comment: I mean its an abstract answer that would fit if its not specified as a sequence but still great insights.